# Inner joining fail with shape file in R

Tags: r, inner-join, r-sf

I wanted to do inner join my data pop (3181 observations) and mymap_un_new (5160 observations)

I used these codes:

```
mymap_un_new <- st_read("name.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

map_and_pop <- inner_join(mymap_un_new, pop)


This message pops up: 

Joining, by = "ADM4_PCODE"
Warning message:
Column `ADM4_PCODE` has different attributes on LHS and RHS of join*
```

Comment: Try with `merge()` instead.

Comment: This is probably not a big issue. It's just a warning (and not an error) telling you that variable `ADM4_PCODE` in the first df has different attributes than in the second df. So, first. Check the resulting df.

Comment: while it is impossible to make sure without access to original data I strongly suspect this is caused by recent updates of {sf} and {dplyr} - see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4917

Comment: now, when i inner join the data file appears with 0 observations. not sure why